# Angular doesn't automatically display the changes in my array of string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr

```
let signalRServerEndPoint = 'https://localhost:44338';
this.connection = $.hubConnection(signalRServerEndPoint);
this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('MessagesHub');

this.proxy.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
  console.log(message); //LOG IS OKAY
  this.listMessages.push(message); // PUSH IS OKAY
  console.log(this.listMessages); // LOG IS OKAY IS OKAY
});
```

The listmessages is an array of string[]. Both console.log() works fine, also the this.listMessages.push(message) works fine because the second console.log display the right array of string. But my problem is in my UI it doesn't automatically populate the new listMessages. It will only display the new populated array when I type something in the textbox or when I click a send button again then it display the latest I've sent earlier. Anyone can help me what's wrong with this?

```html
<div *ngFor="let listMessage of listMessages;let indexs = index;">
    <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" *ngIf="indexs % 2 == 0">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="row">
                <img [src]="createImagePath('userphoto/202431775reyes.jpg')" class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle" style="margin-left: 20px; max-width: 70px; max-height: 50px;" />
                <div class="card-header bg-gradient-success" style="margin-left: 20px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #f1f0f0;">
                    <h4 style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: -10px;" class="text-white">{{listMessage}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h6 class="text-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;">Anthony Earl Cuartero: 12:00 PM | Aug 13</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using `OnPush` change detection somewhere? or messing with `NgZone`? or using some poorly integrated UI lib like jquery?

Comment: Yup I'm using a jquery library because I need it on my signalR. Coz my api is using asp.net mvc.

Comment: I haven't used OnPush change detection.

Comment: there are better libraries to use for signalR that are compatible with angular change detection

Answer (score 5):

This is most probably a case of change detection not being triggered because the reference to the variable isn't modified. You could force it using destructuring operator instead of the push. Try replacing the push statement with

```js
this.listMessages = [...this.listMessages, message];
```

Or you could retain the `push` statement and trigger change detection manually using Angular [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

this.proxy.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
  this.listMessages.push(message);
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: the changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() works perfectly, but is there any other solution aside for this?

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero: I don't think so. You either have to modify the underlying "reference" so CD is triggered automatically or trigger it manually. But be careful while using `detectChanges()`. If you're calling it too frequently (eg. in a loop) it might affect the rendering performance.

Comment: I will be using frequently detectChanges() if I ever implement this. Because I'm using a websocket. I'm implementing some kind of Chat feature. Can you explain more about this (modify the underlying "reference"). I don't understand this one.

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero: Explaining change detection would be beyond the scope of this answer. There are numerous good articles to be found. You may start [here](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular/), [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-change-detection-in-angular) and the official doc linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that jquery isn't well integrated with angular so the events aren't triggering change detection... you should ideally find a way to stop using jquery, you can use signalR without it and there are better integrated signalR / angular libraries out there.

in the meantime, this is untested, but I believe it will work if you leverage `NgZone` to bring it into angular's change detection... something like...

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

this.proxy.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    console.log(message); //LOG IS OKAY
    this.listMessages.push(message); // PUSH IS OKAY
    console.log(this.listMessages); // LOG IS OKAY IS OKAY
  });
});
```

you'll probably want to implement some websocket wrapper service that does this for you with all websocket events so you don't need to use `NgZone` everywhere you use websockets.

Comment: Oh I understand now, it's outside the scope of angular when I used the .push inside the jquery function. Thats why it wont detect the changes. Thanks.

Comment: yea, it's outside of angular's change detection scheme. like i said, best idea is to not use jquery, you don't need it for signalR

Answer (score 0):

You are using push to update Array, so the array reference is same and hence it is  not updating the UI, you can create a new Array using array.filter or spread operator. In short you have to create a new array using old array and updated data. Array is a reference type in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you explain more and show me some example angular codes to use?

Comment: To understand it better, you can further look pure pipe and impure pipe in Angular, impure pipe will give you good idea of reference type and why array.push() do not update UI. You can also check deep copy and shallow copy of Arrays and objects in JavaScript. Refer this URL it may help further: 
  https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/